# How can I make a bluetooth joypad that works fine within Ubuntu work with games and emulators?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, steam, joystick, mame

I have an OUYA bluetooth joypad.

It works fine within Ubuntu 16.04, it was a breeze to pair. I can even use it as a mouse within Ubuntu, and JStest sees it and recognizes every button and axis movement; it also appears as js2 in udev, with js0 and js1 being 2 USB joypads.

But neither Mame, nor Dolphin, not Zsnes, not Steam are able to recognize it.

What is possibly happening and What can I try to fix it?

I have the feeling it might be linked to an issue with only root being able to access some devices, but that is just a hunch.

Comment: Well to check permission, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `ls -l /dev/input/js*` .